# Sohozki's theorem on a given function

Tags: distribution-theory

I am trying to use Sohozki's theorem to find the support of the given singular generalized function:

$$\bigg(\mathscr{P}\frac{\cos{kx}}{x} ,\phi\bigg)=P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos{kx}}{x}\phi(x)\text{d}x$$

However, after re-writing it to

$$\bigg(\mathscr{P}\frac{\cos{kx}}{x} ,\phi\bigg)=P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ikx}}{2x}\phi(x)\text{d}x+P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}}{2x}\phi(x)\text{d}x$$

I get

$$\bigg(\mathscr{P}\frac{\cos{kx}}{x} ,\phi\bigg)=\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \frac{e^{-ikx}}{2x}\phi(x)\text{d}x+\int_{\epsilon}^\infty\frac{e^{-ikx}}{2x}\phi(x)\text{d}x +\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} \frac{e^{ikx}}{2x}\phi(x)\text{d}x+\int_{\epsilon}^\infty\frac{e^{ikx}}{2x}\phi(x)\text{d}x$$

However, from here I am stuck. I have the fact that:

$$P.V.\int \frac{1}{x}\text{d}x=0,$$
and also that

$$\phi(x) - \phi(0) = \phi'(\theta x)x, \theta \in [0, 1],$$

where $\phi$ is the test function (basic function) and it is a locally summable and $\in C^\infty$. Also that  $\phi_k\to\phi$ as $k\to\infty$. However, the  exponential terms make it difficult to reach a conclusion for  this integral, and to find its value by  Sohozki's theorem.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: What is "Sohozki's theorem?"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zahorski_theorem ?

Comment: @md2perpe That does not look like it's related here.  But I have no idea what the OP is trying to do.  The value of the integral depends on $\phi$.  A result can be obtained using the Convolution Theorem in terms of the Fourier Transform of $\phi$.  But this seems useless.

Comment: Now I found a [reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2679.pdf):
"Using Sohozki’s formula $\frac{i}{x+i\epsilon} = \pi\delta(x) + iP(\frac{1}{x})$"

Comment: If you want to find the *support*, why don't you just use the definition of the support?

Comment: I need to prove also that the given function is a singular generalized function. However, the question is mainly about the support. The support is where the function is nonzero. That should be the domain of integration where the integral converges.  But solving that integral is the problem

Comment: @Luthier415Hz The test function has compact support.  And the principal value integral has compact support on $|x|\ge \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks Mark! That should solve the problem

Comment: @Luthier415Hz You're welcome.  Did you want to see why in distribution we have$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{i}{x+i\varepsilon}=\pi \delta(x)+i\text{PV}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$and how this relates to the problem at hand?

Comment: @MarkViola I have worked with the Sohozkis theorem already. So that one is familiar. But I have to admit that I am not sure what the difference is between a regular generalized function and  a singular generalized function. My guess was that the former is continuous, while the latter is not. But if this is right or wrong, and weather that this is the property needed to discern between the two types, I don't know.

Comment: @MarkViola, are you aware of this distinction? Thanks!

Comment: @Luthier415Hz  [This](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Algebra_of_generalized_functions_%28Shirokov%29#Products) and [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) might (or might not) be of use.

Comment: @MarkViola   thanks a lot!

Comment: @Luthier415Hz You're welcome.   My pleasure.